# MVC view cannot reference System.Numerics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, biginteger

Create a new Razor View project using MVC 5.

Add reference to System.Numerics

In my controller I can use BigInteger like this

```
using System.Numerics;
var bi = new BigInteger(100);
```

But in my view, I can't do this:

```
@using System.Numerics
@{
    var bi = new BigInteger(100);
}
```

It kept on complaining that the System.Numerics is not referenced.

Comment: What is your .net Framework version?

Comment: VS2017, Dotnet 4.6.1